# Mac host and Ubuntu guest on virtual box shared folder issue

Tags: server, virtualbox, mac, shared-folders

I have set up ubuntu server on virtual box on my mac. I created a shared folder which appears to be saved and visible in the configuration section on virtual box for the ubuntu server machine.

My only issue is I don't know where this is or how to access it from inside ubuntu server. Does it get it's own directory or do I have to create some sort of a sym-link? 
If I do need to manually tell it to look in the mac for the file how do I reference the mac machine?

Comment: It should be inside `/media` with some name staring with `sf_`.